# Xcode error : while executing 'flutter run' command

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

When I run the command

```
flutter run
```

for my app, it gives the following error :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...

Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                            7.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/Soumya/Desktop/fluttershare/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++/gRPCCertificates.bundle: replacing existing signature
    /Users/Soumya/Desktop/fluttershare/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++/gRPCCertificates.bundle: resource fork, Finder
    information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To
    resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
```

What could be the possible reason behind this and how one can solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you do flutter clean and then build it again?

Comment: @shubham , worked like a charm :) Still I would be interested to know what is the reason behind this.

Comment: I don't have an exact idea of what causes this issue. I get it sometimes after importing some plugins. I have posted the answer below you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: After executing flutter clean command we would see that it will delete the dart-tools folder, android folder and iOS folder in our application with debug file. @SoumyaKantiNaskar

Answer (score 0):

Clean your build and rebuild the app that should solve the issue.

```
flutter clean
```